# How to query JSON values from a column into one JSON array in MS-SQL 2016?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm starting to fiddle out how to handle JSON in MSSQL 2016+

I simply created a table having a ID (int) and a JSON (nvarchar) column.

Here are my queries to show the issue:

First query just returns the relational table result, nice and as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM WS_Test

-- Results:

1   { "name": "thomas" }
2   { "name": "peter" }
```

Second query returns just the json column as "JSON" created my MSSQL.
Not nice, because it outputs the json column content as string and not as parsed JSON.

```
SELECT json FROM WS_Test FOR JSON PATH

-- Results: 

[{"json":"{ \"name\": \"thomas\" }"},{"json":"{ \"name\": \"peter\" }"}]
```

Third query gives me two result rows with json column content as parsed JSON, good.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(json, '$') as json FROM WS_Test

-- Results:

{ "name": "thomas" }
{ "name": "peter" }
```

Fourth query gives me the json column contents as ONE (!) JSON object, perfectly parsed.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(json, '$') as json FROM WS_Test FOR JSON PATH

-- Results:

[{"json":{ "name": "thomas" }},{"json":{ "name": "peter" }}]
```

BUT:
I don't want to have the "json" property containing the json column content in each array object of example four. I just want ONE array containing the column contents, not less, not more. Like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "peter"
    },
    {
        "name": "thomas"
    }
]
```

How can I archive this with just T-SQL? Is this even possible?

Comment: *"So show my issue, I've created a screenshot:"* I can't see images. I suppose you've posted some code as image ? That's not welcome

Comment: You expected output is not different that the 4th query result, it is just a matter of appearance.

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and the first three paragraphs of the [T-SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and  [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Enjoy the edited and now much less readable post and please help instead of just complain please ...

Comment: @MHilgers Now that it's (almost) properly edited (still missing the DDL+DML for sample data) it's much easier to read and more importantly, to copy to a test environment. We complain because we would rather keep the quality of the content on SO as high as possible - that means both questions and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FOR JSON` clause will always include the column names - however, you can simply concatenate all the values in your `json` column into a single result, and then add the square brackets around that.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE WS_Test
(
    Id int, 
    Json nvarchar(1000)
);

INSERT INTO WS_Test(Id, Json) VALUES
(1, '{ "name": "thomas" }'),
(2, '{ "name": "peter" }');
```

For SQL Server 2017 or higher, use the built in `string_agg` function:

```
SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(Json, ',') + ']' As Result
FROM WS_Test
```

For lower versions, you can use `for xml path` with `stuff` to get the same result as the `string_agg`:

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + Json
    FROM WS_Test
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '[')+ ']' As Result
```

The result for both of these queries will be this:

```
Result
[{ "name": "thomas" },{ "name": "peter" }]
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>**DB<>Fiddle**</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c63e867ef8fcf5349bf6b3c86ff80fb)

Comment: Hello Zohar, thx for your detailed answer! This solves my issue! And yes, next time I'll provide better code for reproducing the issue ... ;)

Comment: Glad to help :-)